# Google App Engine - callback when entity is edited/saved from admin

Tags: google-app-engine, admin, datastore

I am interested in having a callback or block of code that runs when I edit and save an entity in the datastore from the Google Console Admin.

Would anyone know how I can do that? Is it possible?